# In C++, can I find in a data structure without generating the whole data structure?

Tags: c++, optimization

I have a function that I'd like to optimize, as it takes 13.4% of the runtime of my program.

This function returns a rather large container, but most of the callers don't need the entire container, as they simply search through the data structure for an element that matches a certain criteria, then throw out the container. However, there are a few callers that make use of the entire container. Additionally, the returned container has a well-known max size, and is generally fairly close to that size on every call of the function.

One way I'd like to optimize this function is to not generate the entire data structure when the caller only needs to search it for a particular item, as this would save about half the time for those callers, as the container nearly always does contain the searched for item. Is it possible to do that, and still have the same function work for the callers that need the whole container? Alternatively, can I implement a function that works for one type of caller, and another that works for the other type of caller, but have them share logic somehow? This is sort of what the whole setup looks like:

The function I want to optimize:

```
vector<Foo> Bar::generate() const {
    vector<Foo> results; //Using a vector is arbitrary, it could be any container
    results.reserve(100);
    int n = 100;
    while (n > 0 && this->shouldGenerate(n)) {
        n--;
        results.emplace_back(...);
    }
    return results
}
```

The most common caller:

```
Foo baz(Bar bar) {
    vector<Foo> items = bar.generate();
    auto it = find_if(items.begin(), items.end(), my_pred);
    if (it == items.end()) {
        return Foo();
    } else {
        return *it;
    }
}
```

The less common caller:

```
void Qux::storeGeneratedFoos(Bar bar) {
    this->foos = bar.generate();
}
```

Comment: You could try using a `static` vector in `Bar::generate()`, and returning a `const vector<Foo> &`.

Comment: Thats a good idea! That would probably help a lot. I'll try it.

Comment: If you want different semantics for the two use cases, I think different functions are definitely the way to go.  So, something like generate_and_find(pred) and generate(), with the common code in the generate-element function or constructor that both call.

Comment: You could pass `my_pred` to the `generate` function and have it call that to work out what it should generate.

Comment: The answers to all your questions are yes, but implementing them would require truly understanding how you are generating the data, so I don't think you have given enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a `static` vector in the function to avoid reallocating space every time, and returning a reference to it:

```
const vector<Foo> &Bar::generate() const {
    static vector<Foo> results; //Using a vector is arbitrary, it could be any container
    results.clear(); //clear from possible previous invocation
    ...
}
```

Then `baz()` could be defined as

```
Foo baz(Bar bar) {
    const vector<Foo> &items = bar.generate();
    ...
}
```

The other function would not have to be modified for this solution.

To reduce the number of generations, you could create a template function as follows:

```
template<class UnaryPredicate>
Foo Bar::generate_if(UnaryPredicate pred) const {
    Foo foo;
    int n = 100;
    while (n > 0 && this->shouldGenerate(n)) {
        n--;
        //instead of 'results.emplace_back(...);' do
        foo = ...;
        if (pred(foo))
            return foo;
    }
    return Foo();
}
```

and change the definition of `baz()` to

```
Foo baz(Bar bar) {
    return bar.generate_if(my_pred);
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea. It lets me avoid the allocation, but not the generation of unnecessary elements. Which in my case is perfect, since the allocation is much more costly than the generation. If someone gives an answer that lets me avoid the generation and the allocation, I'll accept that, otherwise I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend distinguishing both use cases: That way, you can get even faster. Since runtime seems to be an issue, I'll try to be as efficient as possible.

First, generalize the generator:

```
template <typename Storage>
void Bar::generate_impl(Storage & storage) const {
    for (int n = 100; 
         n > 0 && shouldGenerate(n) and storage.go_on(); 
         --n) {
        storage.add(/* some newly built Foo */);
    }
}
```

Then you can have two types of `Storage`. The first will be for your original use case of creating the `vector`. As you see, it will not stop prematurely and store every `Foo` passed:

```
struct MemorizingStorage {
    vector<Foo> data;
    MemorizingStorage() { data.reserve(100); }
    void add(Foo const & f) { data.emplace_back(f); }
    bool go_on() const { return true; }
}; // MemorizingStorage
```

The second one will be for the use case of checking whether some `Foo` was generated. This version will not store anything, but remember whether any `Foo` 'added' was the right one:

```
struct CheckingStorage {
    Foo const & item;
    bool found_it;
    CheckingStorage(Foo const & f) : item(f), found_it(false) {}
    void add(Foo const & f) { found_it = found_it or (item == f); }
    bool go_on() const { return not found_it; }
}; // CheckingStorage
```

And for your users, you provide `Bar` versions using those `Storage`s:

```
vector<Foo> Bar::generate() const {
    MemorizingStorage storage;
    generate_impl(storage);
    return storage; // consider std::move if C++11 is applicable
}

bool Bar::is_generated(Foo const & item) const {
    CheckingStorage storage(item);
    generate_impl(storage);
    return storage.found_it;
}
```

This would be the fastest way I can think of:

- It doesn't require to create any vector when not needed.
- It stops prematurely, when the user only wants to know, if some `Foo` was generated.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make a custom iterator to get the items from `Bar`. Then you can use the custom iterator directly in `find_if` or you can use it to directly initialize a `vector` of items using the two iterator constructor or `assign`:

```
class BarIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, Foo> {
  const Bar* bar;
  int n;
public:
  BarIterator(const Bar& bar, int n);
  Foo operator*() const;
  bool operator==(const BarIterator& other) const;
  bool operator!=(const BarIterator& other) const;
  BarIterator& operator++(){ n--; return *this; }
};

class Bar {
  ...
public:
  BarIterator begin() const { return {*this, 100}; }
  BarIterator end() const { return {*this, 0}; }
  friend class BarIterator;
};

Foo baz(const Bar& bar) {
    auto it = std::find_if(bar.begin(), bar.end(), my_pred);
    if (it == bar.end()) {
        return Foo();
    } else {
        return *it;
    }
}

class Quz {
  std::vector<Foo> foos;
public:
  void storeGeneratedFoos(const Bar& bar) {
    foos.assign(bar.begin(), bar.end());
  }
};
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JJqK5xj4UyBeN4dX)